# JS Ojbect Event onkeyup

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a module like this:

```
let Search = {

    settings: {
        inputField: document.getElementById('search_field')
    },
    init: function() {
        this.bindAction();
    },
    bindAction: function() {
        this.settings.inputField.addEventListener("onkeyup", function(e) {
            let value = this.settings.inputField.value;
            console.log(value);
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    }
};

export default Search;
```

And I import it into my main app like so:

```
import Search from './components/Search';

Search.init();
```

But the onkeyup event doesn't fire.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event name as `onkeyup`, so the listener doesn't fire. The event's name is `keyup`:

```
this.settings.inputField.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
```

You can use `on` when you're assigning a listener by *assigning* to a listener property using dot notation, for example:

```
this.settings.inputField.onkeyup = function(e) {
```

When using `addEventListener`, never prefix the event name with `on` - when assigning to a property, always prefix the event name with `on`.

The other problem is that your calling context is wrong for the listener - inside the listener, `this` will refer to the *element*, not to the `Search` object. Use an arrow function instead, so that the `this` of the parent block will be inherited:

```
this.settings.inputField.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
```